# If exists many tables

Tags: if-statement, sql-server-2016

This may sound stupid, but I would like to know if there is a way to verify if a list of tables exists before doing an action. If I have 12 tables to verify, do I have to repeat “If exists bla bla bla” 12 times?
I tried doing …

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = ’employee_id’
and TABLE_NAME = N’employee_address’
and TABLE_NAME = N’employee_division’ )
```

But it not working. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Your statement will never be true, because table name cannot be one of the these AND at the same time be another of them. In such scenario you can use OR instead of AND, but this will check does at least one of these tables exists. You must either combine 12 EXISTS statements with the names of the tables with AND conditions, or select the count of rows where table name is in list, i.e.:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'employee_id')
and EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'employee_address'
and EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'employee_division' )
```

or

```
IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME in ('employee_id', N'employee_address', N'employee_division' )) = 3)
```